# Inequtions problem - how to calculate total of sales for a determined ROI?

Tags: inequality

A company has determined that the cost of production of X cellphones is according to this formula:

$$ C = 150x + x^2 + 25$$

If each cellphone is sell at 220, how many of them must be produced and sell to achieve earnings of, at least, 1,100.

What I have:

$$Earnings (ROI) = TotalSales - TotalCost$$

Step1:

$$TotalSales - TotalCost \ge 1100$$

Step 2:

$$TotalSales \ge 1,100 + 150x + x^2 + 25$$

Step3:

$$TotalSales \ge x^2 +  150x +  1125$$

Problems:

1.- Is the logic right?
2.- I cannot reduce it more, should I go with the quadratic equation?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

After Cameron comments I have:

$$ 220x \ge x^2 + 150x + 1125 $$

$$ 0 \ge x^2 - 70x + 1125$$

$$ 0 \ge (x - 45)(x - 25)$$

So, I have 2 alternatives:

1.- $$ x \ge 45$$
2.- $$ x \ge 25$$

And my SC is: ${25, \infty-}$. Because the elements of 1 and 2 intersect themselfs at 25 and go to negative infinity. But this is not logic. You cannot produce 0 cellphones and make ROI.

Comment: The gross income is $220x$.  So the details are not at all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Step 1, I think you mean $1100,$ not $1125.$

Now, you're doing fine so far, but what is the formula for Total Sales? (What information haven't you used, yet?)

**Edit**: Very nice work, but you went off the rails a little bit. We do indeed have that $$0\ge(x-45)(x-25),$$ but we can't simply "separate" things the way we could if we had an equation. Note that we either have $$0=(x-45)(x-25)$$ (in which case $x=45$ or $x=25$), or $$0>(x-45)(x-25).$$ Think about what that last one means, though. How can we multiply two real numbers together and get a negative number?

**Added**: You're basically there, now. From $0\ge(x-45)(x-25)$, we have either that

- $x-45\ge0$ and $0\ge x-25,$ or
- $x-25\ge0$ and $0\ge x-45.$

Note that the former is *impossible*! After all, if it were true for some $x,$ then we would have $x-45\ge x-25,$ so $-45\ge-25,$ which is false. Thus, we have that $x-25\ge0$ and $0\ge x-45,$ or equivalently, that $x\ge25$ and $45\ge x.$ The solution set, then, is the set of whole numbers from $25$ to $45,$ inclusive.

**Closing Analysis**:

By our calculations, we've *proved* that the above solution set is correct, but one might wonder how this can be possible--after all, it seems that if one makes and sells more of a product, then one should reasonably expect to make more profit.

The answer to this conundrum lies in analysis of the cost-of-production function $C(x).$ To explain what's going on behind the scenes, I will consider a related function, which I'll call the "just one more" function. Specifically, I wish to consider the function--let's denote it by $J(x)$--that looks at the number of phones $x\ge 0$ that have been produced already, and calculates how much it would cost to make exactly one more phone. It should be clear that the cost of making $x+1$ phones must be equal to the cost of making $x$ phones, plus the "just one more" cost for when $x$ phones have already been made. Put in terms of functions, this means $$C(x)+J(x)=C(x+1)\tag{$\star$}$$ for all $x\ge0.$ Now, note that $$\begin{align} C(x+1) &= (x+1)^2+150(x+1)+25\\ &= (x+1)(x+1)+150x+150+25\\ &= x(x+1)+1(x+1)+150x+175\\ &=x^2+x+x+1+150x+175\\ &= x^2+152x+176,\end{align}$$ and so by $(\star),$ we have $$\begin{align}J(x) &= C(x+1)-C(x)\\ &=x^2+152x+176-(x^2+150x+25)\\ &= x^2+152x+176-x^2-150x-25\\ &= 2x+151\end{align}\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ for all $x\ge 0.$ What does *that* tell us? Well, remember how $J(x)$ was defined in the first place. Note that it costs $\$25$ to make no phones at all, which we obtain from $C(0)=25$ (this is the *startup cost*), then $\$151$ to make the first phone, and each subsequent phone costs $\$2$ more to produce than the previous phone! Basically, their manufacturing process is an increasingly expensive one, but the company isn't upping their prices to compensate, so eventually, they start eating through their earlier profits just to keep it running! That's why they must eventually stop making phones to keep their earnings above any desired level. In fact, if they make $70$ phones or more, the company goes into debt, even if they sell every single phone they produce. *That* is why the described situation conflicts with what we might expect.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27718/discussion-on-answer-by-cameron-buie-inequtions-problem-how-to-calculate-total).

Comment: @Cameron Buie, according to the logic of the question. Should it be answer: "They should produce and sell at least 25 cellphones ... to positiv infinity to earn 1,100 or more ( + infinity)? Why the right limit is 45 inclusive?

Comment: Well, what happens if they make $45$? What about $46$? $47$? The "logic of the question is *precisely the work that we did,* which proved that they must sell no more than $45$ cell phones if they wish to reach the desired earnings level. I will add to my answer to address how this is possible, given the situation described.

Comment: @user3352567: I have updated the answer to explain the seemingly counterintuitive result. Let me know if you have any more questions about this.